# Overline text while clicking checkbox in React-redux

Tags: css, react-redux

Hi im making a todo app in react redux and want the text that is inside of the span with className "text" to be overlined when clicking the checkbox. I get the checkbox to be clicked but I cant get the text to overline. Does anyone know how to do that? :)

This is the return in my jsx code:

```
return (
    <li>
     <span className="text">
       {props.item.name} 
     </span> 

      <span className="checkboxbuttons">
       <label>    
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={props.item.needsMore}
          onChange={handleCheckboxClick} />
        <span className="fakeCheckbox" />  
      </label>

      <button type="button" onClick={handleRemoveButtonClick}>
        <span role="img" aria-label="x">✖️</span> 
      </button>

      </span>

    </li>
  )
```

I have tried this in css to but its not working either:

```
input:checked + .text::after {
  content: '' ;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

This is a link to my github if anyone needs the full code: https://github.com/camillalof/project-todos

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you applying it to the `::after` pseudo element? Also, you're using the `+` sibling CSS operator, but your `input` and your `span.text` are _not_ siblings

Comment: Aha, I understand. Im pretty new to this. Witch Css operator would be the right one to target the span.text when the checkbox being checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get help and solved the problem like this:

```
<li className={props.item.needsMore ? 'checked' : 'unchecked'}>
  all jsx code
</li>
```

Then I targeted the code in CSS with .checked or .unchecked.

Thanks for the help!